# Windows 2008 R2 File Server Cluster Missing Volumes in Share Management

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-server, windows-cluster, cluster-shared-volumes

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 File Server Cluster which is failing to correctly display disk volume information when provisioning a new share, and when undertaking share management. I've been unable to find any information about this problem online, so it's unclear if this is a problem with my disks or with Windows. There are no errors reported either in the front end, or in the Event Log.

The Cluster Disks are attached by iSCSI, and aside from the issue here, are functioning perfectly fine. I can create shares, users can access the shares. A screenshot of one of the file server resources here:

[image: File Server Resource]

The problem appears in two instances:

1. When using the 'Provision a New Share Wizard'

In the Available Volumes list only one of the volumes is shown. If I use the Browse option I can manually select the missing volume and then continue and successfully create a share.

[image: Provision a Share Wizard]

2. When using the 'Share and Storage Management'

Within this on the Shares tab information about the actual shares are present, but any information about that same volume is missing. It's completely absent from the Volumes tab.

[image: Share and Storage Management Shares Tab]

[image]

I have tried moving the file server resource onto another node in the cluster but the problem remained.

I have tried removing the disk and re-attaching to the cluster but this also had no effect.

I've tried to understand how information is being pulled into these views, and monitoring the WMI-Activity Event Log on the node it appears to be making queries to win32_volume and win32_share when they are accessed. I've tried querying this with `get-wmiobject` in Powershell but the information returned for the volumes didn't provide any further insight as to why they might be being omitted (all values were the same for each volume with the exception of the expected such as name, unique ID)

Has anyone experienced anything like this, or have any suggestions for further troubleshooting that could be done.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: did you check that the node you're trying to add the share to is the owner of the disk resource? The cluster node will never see resources that it's not the owner of.

Comment: @SpiderIce Yes, the node it's running on is showing as the owner of the disk resource.

Comment: This might be an MMC issue. Have you tried using RSAT from the other remote PC/server?

Comment: @NetRunner I have tried managing it from other nodes in the cluster, from other 2008 R2 servers in the Domain, and from a Windows 7 machine but problem is the same on all.

I do agree that it does seem like an issue with MMC, but am not sure if this is just a visual glitch or if something is fundamentally wrong.